# Checkboxes/fields in Tables/Bullets not working in Windows

Tags: hyperref, forms

I'm working on a PDF form that includes hyperref package's CheckBox and TextField and I want them to be as list bullets (only CBs) and inside tables (both CBs and TFs).

When working in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS there is no problem (Using pdflatex). The default PDF viewer shows everything correctly, but when I move that file to Windows, none of the installed readers (Foxit, Adobe, Firefox) displayed them correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\MyCheckBox}{\CheckBox[checkboxsymbol=\ding{44}]{}}
\newcommand{\MyTextField}{\TextField{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\paragraph{This is a table:}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \MyCheckBox & text & \MyTextField & text \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{This is a list:}

\begin{itemize}
        \item To buy:
        \begin{itemize}[label=\MyCheckBox]
                \item Bread
                \item Books
        \end{itemize}
        \item To do:
        \begin{itemize}[label=\MyCheckBox]
                \item Solve hunger
                \item Get strong
        \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form field must have a name, the PDF is faulty without it. Be aware that checkboxes with the same name are switched on and off in unison.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\MyCheckBox}{\CheckBox[name=checkbox,checkboxsymbol=\ding{44}]{}}
\newcommand{\MyTextField}{\TextField[name=text]{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\paragraph{This is a table:}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \MyCheckBox & text & \MyTextField & text \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{This is a list:}

\begin{itemize}
        \item To buy:
        \begin{itemize}[label=\MyCheckBox]
                \item Bread
                \item Books
        \end{itemize}
        \item To do:
        \begin{itemize}[label=\MyCheckBox]
                \item Solve hunger
                \item Get strong
        \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am checking (again) the hyperref reference docs, but I am not finding any comment about the (mandatory) purpose of the option `name` (and other options), could you please point out to the correct place to look, if possible? much appreciated

Comment: I don't claim that the hyperref docs are complete here. Actually quite a lot about form fields is not documented and can only be found by looking in the code, or by looking in the pdf reference. Also some parts of the code (e.g. for radioboxes) is faulty. A new implementation of form fields is described in l3pdffield.pdf. See e.g. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/263#issuecomment-1345291099